# Using Regex to replace a specific string occurrence but ignore others based on neighboring characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string

```
   "sub section 15(1) of main section, this might be a <link href="15(1)">15(1)</link>".
```

I want to use the `Regex.Replace` method to replace "15(1)" with a new string value of "15" but only where it occurs individually.

I am  using the following pattern but it's not working.

```
 temp = "sub section 15(1) of main section, this might be a <link href="15(1)">15(1)</link>";    
 temp = Regex.Replace(temp, @"15(1)", @"15");
```

The output string should be:

```
"sub section 15 of main section, this might be a <link href="15(1)">15(1)</link>"
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your post you said you want to replace "15(1)" when it is "used individually." Does that mean when it is surrounded by whitespace?

This approach matches your desired output:

```
string pattern = @"(?<=^|\s)15\(1\)(?=\s|$)";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "15");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

This pattern will match only if the value occurs at the start of the line or is preceded by a whitespace character, and if it is followed by a whitespace character or the end of the line.

Comment: Does .net allow variable length look behinds ?

Comment: @sln yes, it does. Check out this handy [regex flavor comparison](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (note you need to escape the brackets around 1):

```
\W15\(1\)\W
```

where `\W` is a non-word character; or

```
\s15\(1\)\s
```

where `\s` is a whitespace character.

Answer (score 0):

This works `(?<!\S)15\(1\)(?!\S)`